# How to include node_modules in git archive ZIP?

Tags: git, git-archive

I have added `node_modules` in `.gitignore` as usual, because I want to keep it out of my repository. However, I use `git archive` to create a production ZIP that I upload to AWS Elastic Beanstalk and I want to include the `node_modules` so that they don't have to be installed on the EC2 instance, because it has very limited resources.

I looked at `.gitattributes` and I know I can use `export-ignore` to exclude a folder that is not present in `.gitignore`, but here I want to do the opposite. I didn't find anything in the [`git archive` docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive). Is this possible?

Comment: You can use the --worktree-attributes flag with the git archive command. In your case " git archive --format zip --output archive.zip HEAD --worktree-attributes "

Comment: Yeah, `--worktree-attributes` does something else. Seems like someone has asked this question before, just with a different point of view and wording. **tl;dr** it's not possible.